# Does Selenium2Library (1.5 ) support Safari Browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Does Selenium2Library (1.5 ) supports Safari Browser?

"Selenium2Library" keyword documentation for "Open Browser" lists Safari as one of the supported browser. 
Do I need to install any specific driver for Safari?

Please suggest me how to proceed on this.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver is the link you want.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium2Library(1.5) does support safari but you need to do couple of things.

1. Download Selenium jar file from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. Create a Environment variable SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR and give path to
       downloaded jar file.

Example: To setup env variable on mac, make following entry in .bash_profile file
export SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR={path to jar file}

Comment: Downloading the selenium jar file won't automatically install the safari driver.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the safari driver must be installed separately from selenium.  Installation instructions are here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver